# Issue with Host R bookdown generated gitbook on sharepoint

Tags: r, sharepoint-2013, bookdown

I am trying to establish a workflow to host bookdown generated gitbook on Sharepoint (main content publishing platform within corporate). With some tweaks, we can the gitbook on the sharepoint and have no issues with embedded ploty figures.

However, all the figures saved on sub folders could not be displayed. It was found that SharePoint added "_" to the "_main_files" automatically as "files" was reserved for system.

There is some option within _bookdown.yml to config the outputdir such as output_dir: "Outputfolder". However, the "_files" is still automatically added for the folder that saves image.

**Is there a work around with bookdown config to change the sub-directory**? A folder name like "_main_images" would not conflict with sharepoint naming convention.

Comment: do you have a workflow that you use to push the bookdown book to sharepoint? Trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the figure path using the [**knitr** chunk option](https://yihui.name/knitr/) `fig.path` in the first code chunk of your book, e.g.,

````
```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = '_main_images/')
```
````

I'm not entirely sure about the consequences of changing the default `fig.path`, but if your book only contains R plots and no HTML widgets, this change should be fine.

Comment: The knitr chuck works for hosting gitbook on sharepoint. It generated one additional folder outside of book however.

Comment: Yes, that is the price you have to pay, unfortunately. I'd blame it on Sharepoint :)

Comment: In my case, I had to use: fig.path = 'IMAGES/' Nothing with "_" would work. I am leaving this comment in case someone has the same problem.